# Are you and I am going to the store?

Tags: grammaticality

I was taught in college to move the I at the end of the sentence and read it from begin to end. For example; yes, I am going to the store no longer yes, me is going to the store. I believe it becomes Patois ot Patwa language.

Which way is correct?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is rather garbled, so I'm not certain I understand what you are asking.

No native English speaker says *Me am going*, or *Me is going*. The only grammatical and idiomatic form for this in almost all varieties of English is *I am going*.

Many native English speakers say *Me and you are going*, but somebody made up a rule a couple of centuries ago that this is "wrong", and generations of teachers have taught that it is wrong. Generations of teachers have also taught another rule - one of politeness, not grammar - which says you're supposed to mention the other person before yourself, so the standard form is

> You and I are going.

[Jamaican Patois or Jamaican Creole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jamaican_Patois) is a language with mostly English vocabulary, but a very different grammar from English. As I understand it, it uses *mi* where English uses both *I* and *me*.

This is quite different from non-standard varieties of English that sometimes use *me* where standard English requires *I*, as above.